# Jquery Mobile working with nested dialogs

Tags: jquery, dialog, nested, jquery-mobile

I have nested dialogs: dialog1 shows details in edit mode, dialog2 shows customized list of selectable items. I open the dialogs:

```
$.mobile.changePage("dialog1.html", { transition: "slideup" });
```

Dialog2 is opened the same way (opened on dialog1):

```
$.mobile.changePage("dialog2.html", { transition: "slideup" });
```

The issue is that when I close dialog2 on item selection dialog1 gets recreated and all inputs  previously entered get reset. What would be the best way to close dialog2 without affecting dialog1? 
Dialog2 is closed by:

```
 $('#dialog2').dialog('close');
```

Comment: Are you using form method to get the input on the dialogs forms?

Comment: No, I am not using form.